# Ошибка "wrong signature type (_ssl.c:1002)" при попытке подключиться к сайту

Tags: python, requests, ssl

Хочу написать парсер по сайту текстов песен для тренировки на *Python*. Столкнулся с тем, что подключение к сайту `amalgama-lab.com` с помощью метода `get` модуля *requests*, выдаёт ошибку

> SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type (_ssl.c:1002)')))

Код использовал такой:

```
import requests 

print(requests.get('https://www.amalgama-lab.com/songs/t/tones_and_i/dance_monkey.html')
```

Версия *Python* и используемых библиотек актуальны.с настройкой корневых сертификатов все в порядке.
При попытке запустить код с другого компа выдает такую же ошибку.

Какие еще могут быть причины? Как это пофиксить?

P.S. в сети видел ещё одного человека, с такой же проблемой, который пытался подключиться к тому же сайту, может  быть причина в их сертификатах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сервер amalgama-lab.com использует TLS 1.2 и набор криптопримитивов [`ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`](https://ciphersuite.info/cs/TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384/). В этом наборе в качестве хэш функции используется `SHA1-384`.

В OpenSSL есть понятие Security Level. В Ubuntu времён ubuntu-18 дефолтным был уровень SECLEVEL=1. На этом уровне библиотека openssl-1.1.x дозволяла использовать хэш функции семейства SHA1. Поэтому в ubuntu-18 сайт amalgama-lab.com открывается.

Свежии версии линуксов поставляются с OpenSSL 3.0.x и SECLEVEL=2. На этом уровне безопасности хэши SHA1 запрещены. Более того, они запрещены и на уровне SECLEVEL=1. Поэтому вы получаете ошибку `WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE`, так как сервер предлагает воспользоваться запрещённой хэш функцией.

Поэтому вам нужно выбрать минимальный уровень безопасности SECLEVEL=0. Этот уровень считается небезопасным, так как он содержит все поддерживаемые наборы криптопримитивов (ciphersutes), даже если среди них встречаются признанные небезопасными.

Вот пример, как можно настроить опции SSL для requests:

```py
import requests
import ssl
from urllib3 import poolmanager

class TLS_1_2_Seclevel_0(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):

    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """urllib3 PoolManager with 'insecure' SSL settings."""
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        # Insecure ciperhsuite
        ctx.set_ciphers('DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0')
        # No TLS 1.3
        ctx.maximum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
        kwargs["ssl_context"] = ctx
        self.poolmanager = poolmanager.PoolManager(*args, **kwargs)

session = requests.session()
session.mount('https://', TLS_1_2_Seclevel_0())

url = 'https://www.amalgama-lab.com/songs/t/tones_and_i/dance_monkey.html'
res = session.get(url)
print(res)
```

Если всё в порядке, в консоли печатает

```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное,  заработало. Не могли бы вы посоветовать литературу по ssl сертификатам и https?

Comment: @ОлегПронин [Bulletproof SSL and TLS](http://www.altair.pw/pub/doc/ssl/ssl/bulletproof-ssl-and-tls.pdf) - первые восемь глав и глава 11 про OpenSSL. Книге уже 10 лет, она малёхо устарела в части допустимых алгоритмов и возможных атак, но как введение в предмет - очень даже.

Comment: @ОлегПронин если заработало, пожалуйста, примите ответ.

Comment: Принял, извиняюсь, я на stackoverflow новенький, пока разбираюсь, как тут все работает, спасибо за литературу.